# Is it possible to run Windows 10 entirely from a USB drive in 2021?

Tags: malware, liveusb

I am in a class that is requiring a "lockdown browser", which is a shame, but I am still really interested in the content of this class. But I do not have a Windows machine, and given Lockdown's infamy as malware which damages machines it is installed onto and its resistance to being used in a VM, I want to install Windows 10 on a flashdrive to use this.

As a compromise, I am trying to create a Windows "live USB". The best method, as I understood, was "Windows To Go", which was discontinued in 2019.

There exist other answers and tutorials, but many of them are outdated.

So: I want to **run Windows 10 entirely off of the USB**, preferably with persistent storage. Is this possible in 2021, and if so, what is the recommended method?

Comment: Is it possible, of course, it's possible, but it will be a slow and horrible existence.  You can do it with the current version of Rufus. Windows to Go instances cannot be updated.  In order to boot a Windows to Go installation you would need complete and total control over the boot order configuration of the device.

Comment: I did this once using Minitool or Easeus partition wizard not sure, But I checked the site of both and can't find any option that claims to do such thing on the description of the current versions, not even on the paid version....I remember to be not able to use Windows to go cause my flash drive was not compatible.

Comment: I found a pretty recent tutorial using Hasleo WinToUSB: https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/resource/install-windows-10-on-usb-flash-drive.html

Comment: Another tutorial using EASEUS OS2Go: https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-resource/create-portable-windows-usb-drive.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, installing such obtrusive, preemptive software seems risky to me, too. [VTLUUG states,](https://vtluug.org/wiki/Respondus_LockDown_Browser) "Features of the browser could be construed to ... be purposefully harmful to systems... Respondus Monitor... allows the proctor to spy on users through their webcam."

Here are two suggestions to reduce risk:

- Install Windows on *another* partition, or better [on an external SSD or HDD](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3185777/how-to-install-windows-on-an-external-drive.html) or on an internal drive that can be swapped out, to isolate obnoxious software from the main partition.
- It *might* be possible to run it on Linux, which can easily run from USB. For example, [Ubuntu Live with persistent storage](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) allows you run from the USB as if it were the HDD... with one *caveat*: use a *very* fast USB or flash or SSD drive, because saving to flash is *excruciatingly* slow, compared to an internal HDD. Of course, that applies to Windows, as well.
  [UbuntuForums has a post by boblizar](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1702183) stating it *is* possible, though complex. This question has also been [raised on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873108/respondus-lockdown-browser-required-can-only-use-a-linux-system). All comments seem to indicate it is non-trivial to get that browser working on Linux, though.